# Nginx + PHP File Upload issue

Tags: php, linux, nginx

I am experiencing the following issue when uploading a file via phpMyAdmin, MODx or Wordpress. In the PHP application itself I am receiving a success message but the file is not uploaded. The nginx error.log prints the following messages:

```
[warn][..] a client request body is buffered to a temporary file...
FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  File upload error - unable to create a temporary file in Unknown on line 0...
```

I am running CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core) with Nginx 1.8.0 and PHP 5.4.16. This setup was working before updating from CentOS 7.1 to 7.2.

Here are the steps that I already tried to solve the problem:

- sys_get_temp_dir() -> /tmp
- /tmp has permissions 1777
- PHP is running as user nginx
- it is plenty of free disk space available
- post_max_size, upload_max_filesize and client_max_body_size are all set to 50m

I am running out of ideas...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple Solution:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart php-fpm nginx
```

Fixed the problem. I don't know why, but now it is working like a charm.

Comment: It's almost certain somebody has deleted the directory that's created in the /tmp area for both these processes nginx and php-fpm to write to. The processes then attempt to write to a non-existent directory. Restarting them recreates the directories and which makes it work again.